# Can perl replace multiple keywords with their own substitute word in one go?

Tags: regex, perl

Consider a textfile with the contents:

```
apple apple pear plum apple cherry pear apple  
cherry plum plum pear apple cherry pear pear apple plum
```

And consider the perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe "s/apple/green/g and s/pear/yellow/g and s/plum/blue/g and s/cherry/red/g" < fruits.txt
```

This replaces every fruit with its colour.
Now, could this be done in a single s///g somehow, instead of the above four?

I am also concerned about the order of the fruit words.
If my sample does not include "apple", none of the other replacements will complete.
How should I fix that?

Please note: I want to keep the solution as a one-liner.
So defining hashes, reading in files and other solutions requiring many lines of perl code do not take me forward.

It is more of a curiosity rather than a life-or-death question a project would depend on.
Just troubles me for some days now and thought a more experienced perl user out there could help with the solution in a heartbeat, or put me out of my misery by telling me straight that this cannot be done in perl the way I want.

Comment: I think the original is more legible, but note that the behavior is different than the suggested solutions if any of the patterns or strings are substrings of other patterns or strings (sequential substitutions vs a single pass)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
perl -E 'my %h = qw(apple green foo bar); say "apple foo" =~ s/(apple|foo)/$h{$1}/rge;'
```

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was after. The key is the $h{$1} form, thanks for pointing that out, ruz! I must admit that mkb and ikegami provided a more complete solution and I will actually use something they suggested, but I will mark this answer as the winner as it includes the key I was missing.

Answer (score 15):

Replace

```
perl -pe's/apple/green/g and s/pear/yellow/g and ...' fruits.txt
```

with

```
perl -pe's/apple/green/g; s/pear/yellow/g; ...' fruits.txt
```

However, the following is faster and doesn't have a problem with a=>b b=>c:

```
perl -pe'
   BEGIN {
      %subs=qw(apple green pear yellow plum blue cherry red);
      $re=join "|", map quotemeta, keys %subs;
      $re = qr/($re)/;
   }
   s/$re/$subs{$1}/g;
' fruits.txt
```

Other potential issues:

- What if you want to replace `apple` but not `apples`?
- What if the hash has keys `bee` and `beer`?

Both problems can be solved using suitable anchoring (e.g. `$re = qr/\b($re)\b/`). The second can also be solved by sorting the keys by decreasing length (`sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } keys %subs`).

(You can remove the line breaks I added for readability.)

Comment: any explanation on how the third example works? Never used Perl but this appears to do what I am trying to accomplish, kinda

Comment: @user5359531, It dynamically builds the regex pattern `(apple|pear|plum|cherry)` from the keys of `%subs`, then uses it in `s///` to replace instances of those sequences with the corresponding value in `%subs`. The `BEGIN` block is only executed once, before the loop over the input file.

Answer (score 5):

`perl -pe '%a=qw(apple green pear yellow plum blue cherry red);$b=join("|",keys %a);s/($b)/$a{$1}/g' < fruits.txt`

Comment: Presumably if the strings were known in advance you could use a hashref literal as part of the replacement expression?

Comment: @Neil, If you create the hash inside the replacement expression instead of outside the s///, you have to repeat all the keys in the search expression.

Comment: I don't like how mkb creates the hash and compiles the regex for every line of the input, but it's not I who downvoted this good answer. (My answer doesn't have that problem, but it's a little bit longer.)

Comment: Perhaps this should be `join "\b|\b"` to avoid things like `pineapple` turning into `pinegreen`. Also, consider sorting the keys in length order to further reduce such cases.

Comment: Sure ikegami's BEGIN block gives this a nice touch, but this is already an excellent solution as is. Its main moral for me is that I shouldn't have written off the use of hashes in the first place, you just demonstrated that it can nicely coexist with a one-liner solution and does help to simplify an awful lot of trouble. I had a difficult time deciding between this answer and ruz's one. I hope you don't mind that I figured the extra points do more good to him than to you.

Comment: @ikegami Sure, I just wasn't clear as to what Keve counted as one go, and I got it wrong, as it turns out.

Comment: @Neil, you didn't really. Keve himself wasn't clear as to what he counted as one go, as it turns out! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the problem, I think I'd just be a bit sloppy and look at every run of non-whitespace. If it's something interesting, I replace it. If not, I put the same text back.

```
 $ perl5.14.2 -nE 'print s/(\S+)/$h{$1}?$h{$1}:$1/rge}BEGIN{%h=qw(apple green pear yellow plum blue cherry red)'
```

If the problem is any more complicated than that, my one-liner would look like:

```
 $ perl fruits2color
```

Several of the other answers bit up a regex by joining strings. In a non-one-liner program, I'd probably do that with something like [Regex::Assemble](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aAssemble) or [Regexp::Trie](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Regex%3a%3aTrie). Those modules can build efficient alternations.

Comment: I am impressed by your replacement string trick, Brian! I like this very much. But your curly braces are not properly placed. I believe the closing-one between "/rge" and "BEGIN" belongs to the end, following "red)" but before the single quote. You probably moved the BEGIN block from the front to the back. ;-)

Comment: Nope, those braces are in the right place. There are two hidden ones from -n that you don't see. Did you try the one-liner?

Comment: You are right. Actually, doubly so. Because the hidden braces are there due to the -n, and No I didn't try before opening my mouth. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Who said that hashes can't remember their order :) ?

> [**How can I make my hash remember the order I put elements into
>   it?**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-make-my-hash-remember-the-order-I-put-elements-into-it%3f)
>
> Use the [`Tie::IxHash`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aIxHash) from
>   CPAN.
>
> ```
> use Tie::IxHash;
> tie my %myhash, 'Tie::IxHash';
>
> for (my $i=0; $i<20; $i++) {
>     $myhash{$i} = 2*$i;
> }
>
> my @keys = keys %myhash;
> # @keys = (0,1,2,3,...)
> ```

---

```
$ perl -MTie::IxHash -pe '
         BEGIN { tie %h, "Tie::IxHash";
                 %h = qw< apple green pear yellow >;
               }
         s<($_)>/$h{$1}/g for keys %h;
        ' file
```